# How do I fix AttributeError: "list" attribute has no attribute 'astype' in list-comprehensions?

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension, contains

Basically I am trying to use contains method inside list comprehensions. But I am facing a problem doing this.

I've already tried using

```
[x.apply(', '.join).str.contains('|'.join(searchfor)) for x in losdata["Crime_Type"] ]
```

in the code. It doesn't work.

```
searchfor = ["BURGALORY","ROBBERY","THEFT","STOLEN",
            "SNATCHING","STEALING","FELONY","PICKPOCKET","BUNCO","EMBEZZLEMENT"]
losdata["Crime_Type"] = ["Burglary" if(x.astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))) 
                         else "TBC"
                         for x in losdata["Crime_Type"]
                        ]
print(losdata.head())
```

losdata['Crime_Type'] is an **object** data-type. losdata is a pandas dataframe.
What I expect is that for every object in losdata['Crime_Type'], I should be able to use contains() inside list comprehensions. I have seen solutions like

```
df[df['A'].str.contains('a')==True]
```

'A' is just any column name. 
But I haven't figured how to fix it in my case.

Comment: But `df['A']` isn't a string or a list of strings. It's a pandas Series.

Comment: `x.astype(str).str.contains` should probably just be `x.str.contains`

Comment: `astype` is a method pandas Series or DataFrame.  The error says that `x` in the comprehension is a list.  You, we, need to know what `losdata["Crime_Type"]` is (a pandas Series?), and what it contains.  Strings, numbers, lists or what?

Comment: `str.contains` is a method of a pandas Series.  The docs examples show it applied to the whole series, not rows/elements of a series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to code this.

```
losdata["Crime_Type"] = ["BURGLARY" if(x.find("BURGALORY")>0 or x.find("ROBBERY")>0 or x.find("THEFT")>0 or x.find("STOLEN")>0 or x.find("SNATCHING")>0 or x.find("STEALING")>0)
                         else "OTHER"
                         for x in losdata['Crime_Type']
                        ]
print(losdata.head())
```

It works but still waiting for more effective way.